# magento rest api 500 internal server error while fetch all products

Tags: api, rest, magento

when I trying to fetch all product list with rest api.

http://magento-11498-25844-78339.cloudwaysapps.com/api/rest/products

it shows 500 internal server error

[image]

Comment: Please guide me for resolve this error.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I am not able to open this url http://magento-11498-25844-78339.cloudwaysapps.com/api/rest/products

Answer (score 0):

As i can see Magento rest API is not configured. Below  two steps are required. 
Preparing for REST API

These steps are required for utilizing REST API resources:

```
1. Set up permissions for REST resource operations from Magento Admin Panel.
2. Configure the attributes for different users types in Magento Admin Panel. There are 3 different types of users in accessing the data: Admin, Customer, and Guest. Admin is the backend logged in user, Customer is the fronted logged in user, and Guest is a non-logged in fronted user.
```

Also you can follow below url for better assistance.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

Comment: Please follow my below answer

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below Steps which is working fine for me. 
1. Login to the admin panel 
2. System >> Web services >> Rest Roles
3. Then click on guest then choose catalog all item then save the role
4. Then Click on System >> Web services >> Rest Attributes then Choose all then save.

Hope It will work fine. Thanks

Please look at the screens shots too. [image]

Comment: After completed above steps.I am getting again same error