# Magento 1.9.2.2 REST API - 500 internal server error in Android

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services, magento-1.9

I am newbie in Magento , working on REST API.From the documentation I found API for the list of products as http://myhost.com/api/rest/products?page=1&limit=20

I have set guest user "all" permissions and it is working fine when I am calling in web browser.But at mobile application (in android/iOS) it is throwing

> 500 internal server error

Is there any other settings in magento to make it work properly ?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: No luck @M.Baraka , working in browser and postman but throwing 500 error in mobile application

Comment: postman for me still get access denied, I set the authorization there with token and secret. Is there something else to do in postman?

Comment: did you set resource access 'all' for guest user under system -> web services -> REST rolls. Let me know if it helps ?

Comment: okay, i set the guest roles to "retrieve" on everything, now postman can work, but requesting on /products returns list of empty items.I'm trying to use REST through Android not php.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question , I am facing same issue , it is working in web browser and postman but throwing 500 internal server error in Android. If you are not getting 500 error , can you please share your codes here ?

Comment: I still cannot make it work on phone sorry

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ8Zx.png, check that image. For me, I had it on costume and had all checked, when i contacted the company i'm with, they changed it to all, and now for some reason my phone as a "guest" can get data, BUT using authentication still fails with error 500. I can post code if you want.  
Check link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150900/magento-rest-api-500-internal-server-error-while-fetch-all-products

Comment: @SachinVairagi Did you find the solution?

Comment: @Rathinam, yes I was from Android end, they have resolved and it is working fine.

Comment: @SachinVairagi for me if i try to get customer list using http://localhost/anusthana/api/rest/customers?limit=2  i am getting error, can i get idea how to resolve it? error screenshot : https://snag.gy/MyLNJI.jpg

Comment: Please check M. Baraka's comment - i.stack.imgur.com/HZ8Zx.png, check that image. For me, I had it on costume and had all checked, when i contacted the company i'm with, they changed it to all, and now for some reason my phone as a "guest" can get data, BUT using authentication still fails with error 500. I can post code if you want. Check link

Comment: @SachinVairagi Yes i did that, still i am getting error https://snag.gy/eg3zmX.jpg  can you pls help me?

Comment: do you have google hangout?

Comment: live:a79cb6afd11b2944 Skyp ID